# DB2 Select statement with join using aggregate functions

Tags: sql, join, db2, aggregate

I have two tables in DB2, and I want to issue a single query for multiple rows in the 1st table, including one or more aggregate functions on relevant data in the 2nd table.

```
cust
cust_id    | first_name    | last_name
--------------------------------------
1          | jim           | smith
2          | carol         | angelo
3          | mike          | jones

order
order_id   | cust_id       | amount
--------------------------------------
123        | 2             | 7.00
124        | 1             | 12.00
125        | 2             | 2.00
126        | 2             | 13.00
127        | 3             | 25.00
```

I want to query these tables and include specific columns from the cust table, while also including aggregates from the order table.

desired output for selecting only cust_id in (1, 2)

```
cust_id | first_name | last_name  | order_count | order_total
--------------------------------------------------------------
1       | jim        | smith      | 1           | 12.00
2       | carol      | angelo     | 3           | 22.00
```

I know this has a simple solution but I don't understand if it involves Group By, or Join, or both... Thanks for helping with the query sql.

Comment: Have you tried laying down any kind of code? If so, consider updating your post with it, so that we can set you on the right track accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `JOIN` to merge data from both tables, and `GROUP BY` to apply `count()` and `sum()` on the grouped data :

```
select c.cust_id, c.first_name, c.last_name, count(o.amount) as order_count , sum(o.amount) as order_total
from cust c
inner join orders o on o.cust_id = c.cust_id
where c.cust_id in (1,2)
group by c.cust_id, c.first_name, c.last_name
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/T22BzD-1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Also, that db fiddle tool will be incredibly useful, so thanks for the demo link as well!

Comment: Furthermore, if this is issued for a customer that doesn't have any orders, the result set doesn't include any rows for that customer. Because I want to still list the customer's name, and total of 0 orders for 0 dollars, I changed the inner join to a left outer join to solve for this.